# How to solve node.js ENOENT error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using express.js to run this code:

```
var repl = require("repl");
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var core = require("./testtaker-core.js");
core.init(io);
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.all('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile("index.html");
});
app.all('/*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/*");
});
server.listen(8080);
server.on('close', function () {
  console.log("Server shutdown successfully");
});
repl.start({
  prompt: ">"
}).context.server = server;
```

I am getting this error:

Error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\Users\Timothy\tt\x' at Error (native)

I know that I did not link to \x in any of my files. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please put full stack trace ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone!
I solved my problem with this code:

```
var repl = require("repl");
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var core = require("./testtaker-core.js");
core.init(io);
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + req.originalUrl);
});
server.listen(8080);
server.on('close', function () {
  console.log("NOTE: server shutdown successfully");
});
repl.start({
  prompt: "REPL>"
}).context.server = server;
```

It turns out the x was a * I put in because I misunderstood [this](http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html) documentation page. I thought that including the * would allow it to route to any files necessary.